# iOS redirect back to apps

Tags: ios

I need help , googling also put me at no clue thus i'll post here for guidance and assist.

My situation is that I want the app delegate.m after when you press Ok, I want a simple redirect back to another view . Is that possible?

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Daily Vibes"
                                                        message:notification.alertBody
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

Is it possible to do ?? After they click the cancel button Okay then they'll just be redirect back to the apps a specific page???

Comment: Do you mean detecting the pressed button on the UIAlertView, and doing something?

Comment: @nlee918, yes exactly . It will redirect to a view page @ Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Make your app delegate conforms to the UIAlertViewDelegate protocol, and add this code:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if([title isEqualToString:@"Okay"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Okay was selected.");
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        MyViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
        [(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
    }
    else if([title isEqualToString:@"Hello"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Hello was selected.");
    }
}
```

The delegate captures the selected button, checks the title, and acts accordingly. In this case, since you are in the app delegate, you have to do a manual push of the view controller (you aren't in a view controller, so theres no pushing allowed)

Comment: Already conform to UIAlertViewDelegate already.

I'm getting error in this line :

MyViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];

Is it MyViewController or UIViewController???

@nlee918

Comment: MyViewController is your view controller. You have to import the class of the view controller you are using, and set it to that. If the viewcontrolelr you wanted to direct to was named HelloViewController, you would import HelloViewController.h, and change MyViewController to HelloViewController. You will also have to add an identifier.

Comment: I can't really explain it in the comments since it is a completely different question, but the documentation is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStoryboard/instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:

Comment: ouh , you meant identifier for UI . I thought something else , don't worry i'll get the idea when I'm starting to do the UI's.